# get_theme_mode & set_theme_mode in block editor

Tags: theme-development, block-editor, get-theme-mod

### Background:

I'm transitioning from a traditional theme to a block theme.

Previously, I used `customize_register` to store theme data like footer credits, social links, etc. and retrieve them using `get_theme_mod`.

### Challenge:

In block themes, I need common attributes across all instances of a block (e.g., footer logo, copyright text).

Changing an attribute in one instance should update it globally.

What's the recommended approach to managing these shared attributes in block themes?

### Key Points:

#### Theme Mods:

Are they still suitable for this purpose in block themes?

How can they be effectively accessed and updated within blocks using JSX?

#### Alternative Solutions:

Are there better options for managing shared block attributes?

What are the pros and cons of different approaches?

#### Best Practices:

What are the recommended practices for handling shared data in block themes?

How can I ensure a consistent user experience and avoid potential conflicts?